# Can you explain why mqtt is called a broker and not a server?

Tags: mqtt

mqtt is called a broker and not a server? difference between http and mqtt in perspective of server and broker?

Comment: HTTP is a request-response protocol with a server and a client. Message queueing is an asynchronous messaging system with clients and a broker but no real server, as the clients are really sending to each other. 'Broker' is more specific than 'server' here.

Answer (score 1):

Because Messaging brokers mediate between a number of clients, rather than "serving" a single client in a request response pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Clients send messages to the broker, which then uses some internal logic to re-send those messages to other clients. It doesn't in general respond to the original client.

Because these messages don't get a "response", they're not called *requests*. They're called "publications".

And so the broker isn't really "serving" the client with a response. It's just re-sending the message to other clients.

That's why it's not called a server.

But, honestly, the message *is* a request (a request to re-send), and the broker does provide a service (the re-sending service) so I would still call it a server. But most people don't. I personally find these distinctions pretty vague and pointless, and wouldn't give them too much importance.